# JwtModule.registerAsync not working in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, nestjs, dotenv

I'm working on a NestJS project and I need to use JWT with `.env` configuration. It generates the token but when trying to access the secured url(With Authorization header), it just returns the Unauthorized message.

jwt.strategy.ts

```html
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtPayload } from './interfaces/jwt-payload.interface';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {

    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

auth.module.ts

```html
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async () => ({
        secretOrPrivateKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        signOptions: {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME,
        },
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

main.ts

```html
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { ApiModule } from './api/api.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  dotenv.config({ path: './.env'});
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApiModule);
  const port = process.env.APP_PORT;

  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

Looks like **`JwtModule.registerAsync`** is not working with environment variables. I've tried many things but it always fails.
If I change environment variables in `auth.module.ts` for static data, then it works fine.
Something like this:

```
secretOrPrivateKey: 'secretKey',
signOptions: {
  expiresIn: 3600,
},
```

**UPDATE**
Project structure

```
- src
    - api
        - auth
            - interfaces
                jwt-payload.interface.ts
            auth.controller.ts
            auth.module.ts
            auth.service.ts
            jwt.strategy.ts
            index.ts
        api.module.ts
        index.ts
    main.ts
- test
.env
```

My main.ts looks like this now.

```html
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { ApiModule } from './api/api.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  dotenv.config({ path: resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApiModule);
  const port = process.env.APP_PORT;

  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

You see that my `.env` is in the root of the project.

Answer (score 17):

If you use [config module](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) you can do something like this:

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
    return {
      secret: config.get<string>('JWT_SECRET_KEY'),
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: config.get<string | number>('JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME'),
      },
    };
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

I also had a problem with initializing `JwtModule` and this code solved it.

Comment: I had an issue reading the secret key from the env file and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

Assuming you have a `.env` file and it's in the correct place, for this to work you need to configure dotenv before everything, **even imports**

```
// configure dotenv before every thing, even imports
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { resolve } from 'path';
dotenv.config({ path: resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });

// rest of the code
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ApiModule } from './api/api.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApiModule);
  const port = process.env.APP_PORT;

  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

---

## Why?

Because when you do something like this

```
import { ApiModule } from './api/api.module'
```

What happens is that you are running the code from the file `./api/api.module` and that file will look like this (I'm using the other file you showed in you question just so it's more clear to you)

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async () => ({
        secretOrPrivateKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        signOptions: {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME,
        },
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And when you import it, this whole file is "executed" and the references of `process.env` are "set" before you set `dotenv`.

So you need to "run" the code that sets the `dotenv` before you "execute" the code where you use `process.env`.

## Observations:

I still recommend using the [Configuration](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) that is already built-in and then you should use the async methods and inject the configuration service (just like some other answer).

But if you do want to use `process.env`, setting `dotenv` before everything is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt()` for `process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME`.
The `expiresIn` parameter should be a number. In your case it's string.

Comment: This solved my same problem!

Answer (score 1):

I'm recently worked on that and just like you I tried many things but no one worked for me .. instead,  that one did!

```
 @Module({ 
    imports: [
    AnyModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async _ => {
        return {
          secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
          signOptions: { expiresIn: "120s" }
        }
      }
    }),
  ]
```

I use *JwtModule.registerAsync()* method with **async** *useFactory* and without injection of *ConfigService*.

Then into my **AppModule.ts**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({
        isGlobal: true,
      })
```

With this, We tell to **ConfigModule** that it works globally and We can use it on any module without import

In short We need to import **JwtModule** and use *registerAsync* method calling *userFactory* object like ***async*** too. With all this done, **JwtModule** awaits to **AppModule.ts** was create for call our *process.env*, **ConfigModule** in fact.

Thanks everybody for the answer and [NestJs Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) too.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me your code works:

[image: Edit Nest.js JWT Auth]

Where is your `.env` file?
Your configuration `dotenv.config({ path: './.env'});` is equal to the default configuration `dotenv.config();` where the `.env` file is looked up in your project root directory (and not in `src`).

If you want to put your `.env` file in the `src` directory, use the following configuration

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
dotenv.config({ path: resolve(__dirname, '.env') });
```

---

Instead of directly using your environment variables, I'd recommend encapsulating them in a `ConfigService`, see the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration). This makes it much easier to test and refactor.

Comment: That's weird, I doesn't want to work on my localhost. Maybe node version or something? I have node version v11.5.0

Comment: Where did you put your `.env` file?

Comment: I'll update my post with my project structure. I wonder if nodemon has to do with this

Comment: Don't think so, the codesandbox example also runs nodemon

Comment: I don't know what it could be :S. For sure I have the same thing on my local, but it throws unauthorized everytime.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log` your `process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY` in your `JwtStrategy`? Is it undefined? Is it defined in the `JwtModule` import?

Comment: I added a log in JwtModuledeclaration, also in JwtStrategy. They log this: `JWTModule: secretKey`and `JWTStrategy: secretKey`... valid value for both

Comment: If your code works on a different machine and your environment variables are resolved correctly then the only thing I could think of are your dependencies. Make sure to run the latest versions with `npm update` and completely clean and reinstall your dependencies once. Other than that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I created a custom JwtAuthGuard and logged everything inside the `handleRequest` method... somehow `expireIn: 3600` wasn't working. I changed it to `1d`and it worked. Thanks for your help!!