# Why is .env undefined?

Tags: nestjs

app.module.ts

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            isGlobal: true
        }),
        MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_DB_URI, {useFindAndModify: false}),
        UsersModule,
        RolesModule,
        AuthenticationModule,
        TwoFactorAuthModule,
        RememberPasswordModule,
        RegistrationLinkModule
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

authentication.module.ts

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        JwtModule.register({
            secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
        }),
        UsersModule,
        TwoFactorAuthModule,
        RememberPasswordModule,
        RegistrationLinkModule
    ],
    controllers: [AuthenticationController],
    providers: [AuthenticationService]
})
export class AuthenticationModule {}
```

In AuthenticationModule process.env is undefined. But if I use it in AuthenticationService it works fine. How can I use process.env in module file?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148743/jwtmodule-registerasync-not-working-in-nestjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Francois said, you *can* make the `config()` method the first thing in your `main.ts` file. Keep in mind this **must** be done before you import **any** file that has a decorator using `process.env`.

Another option would be to use a package like `@golevelup/profiguration`, which is similar to `dotenv` and can be used inside of decorators.

The last option, that Istiyak Tailor references is using the `@nestjs/config` package and the `ConfigModule` and `ConfigService`. For this, you should make use of the asynchronous registration methods, such as `registerAsync` and `forRootAsync`. Then you can use a configuration like

```js
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
    secret: config.get('JWT_SECRET'),
  })
})
```

(similar for the `MongooseModule` but using `forRootAsync` instead of `registerAsync`)

This tells Nest to wait for the `ConfigModule` to finish instantiating and the use the `ConfigService` inside of the instantiation for the `JwtModule` and `MognooseModule`.

You could also [use a configuration class](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#class-providers-useclass) instead of `useFactory`, but they essentially are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to import dotenv and configure it at the beginning of your `main.ts` file before you bootstrap your application.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

async function bootstrap() { ... }
```

As stated in [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) doc: *"As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv."*

Comment: It's not a good practice to use dotenv in nest.js. There's already a separate module configured in nest.js to retrieve env variables i.e ConfigModule

Comment: I agree a better approach would be to use the ConfigModule: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration